# How to place the browser scrollbar in a way that it does not take up space on the page?

Tags: scrollbar

Is it possible to place the scrollbar in way that it does not take up space and placed above the page? And I also I need to make the scrollbar track transparent. Only the scrollbar thumb should have some color to be visible.